# Visual Studio C# - only compile changed .cs files

Tags: c#, compilation

I notice that when I change a single c# code file and build the project, that it starts to compile *all* source files in the project. For large projects, this means that most of the time is spent re-compiling files that have not change since the last build.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio or MSBuild to only compile changed c# files?

NOTE: this is not incremental building as far as I understand it, that only re-builds a project if a file has changed for that project. What I'm asking is incremental re-build *within* one project. This is similar to the behavior of C++ compiling: only changed CPP files are compiled.

Comment: It has to recompile all files/projects that are dependent on that single file you changed. Because it could have an impact on these.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do this in C#. It compiles an assembly from a project, not from separate files. I used to work with **pretty huge** projects and never met a problem of long compilation of **single project**. Perhaps, your project is too complex and needs to be separated or you need to improve your hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The project is quite large indeed, and 95+ percent of compile time is spent on compiling unchanged files. Still the compile time for the project is only in the order of 15-20 seconds or so, so it's not a huge problem. Also I find that disabling warning 1591 speeds up the re-compile significantly.